# Rails error handling with validation and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to catch the validation errors and return them via jQuery.  I but it seems to have a no method error when the tweet is valid.  And does not run the else format.js and trigger the failure.js.erb

**hashtag_controller.rb**

def create

```
    @hash_create = Hashtag.create_hashtag(params[:hashtag])
    Hashlog.create_hashlog(params[:hashtag])
    @random_hashtag_pull = Hashtag.random_hashtags_pull
    @leaderboard = Hashtag.leaderboard_history_current
    respond_to do |format|
        if @hash_create
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js 
    else
        format.js { render :action => "failure" }

        end
    end
end
```

**hashtag.rb**

```
  hashtag_regex = /[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/i 

  validates :hashtag,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :within => 3..20 },
                    :format   => { :with => hashtag_regex }


 class << self

def create_hashtag(hashtag)                #creates new tweetvstweet for inputed hashtag with # for guests
    dash = "#"
    @hashtag_scrubbed = [dash, hashtag].join.downcase
    (User.current_user ? User.current_user.twitter : Twitter).search("%#{@hashtag_scrubbed}", :lang => "en", :count => 100, :result_type => "mixed").results.map do |tweet|
        unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
      create!(
        tweet_id: tweet.id,
        text: tweet.text,
        profile_image_url: tweet.user.profile_image_url,
        from_user: tweet.from_user,
        from_user_name: tweet.user.name, 
        created_at: tweet.created_at,
        hashtag: @hashtag_scrubbed,
        view_count: "0",
        wins: "0"
          ) 
        end  
    end
end
```

**error when valid**

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 388ms

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `create!' for #<Array:0x007ffa911efb20>):
  app/controllers/hashtags_controller.rb:16:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/hashtags_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

**error when invalid**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 900ms

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Hashtag is too short (minimum is 3 characters), Hashtag is invalid):
  app/models/hashtag.rb:45:in `block in create_hashtag'
  app/models/hashtag.rb:34:in `map'
  app/models/hashtag.rb:34:in `create_hashtag'
  app/controllers/hashtags_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be calling `tweet.create!` instead of just `create!` in your hash_tag.rb?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, it worked fine until I tried to turn the respond to into an ifelse

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (worked for me):

```
`if @hash_create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :action => "failure" }
  end
end
```

`